# New to VBA and I'm trying to create a function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, ms-office

I'm attempting to make a user-defined function that mimics my formula. I need something more efficient than my formula.

I've tried VBA and using the above formula as is. This is ineffective for the larger datasets I'm working with.

```
=IF((AND(B2>=65,A2>=7)),"Greenbox",IF((AND(B2>10,A2=0,B2= "")),"Balance",IF((AND(B2>=65,A2<3)),"Yellowbox",IF((AND(B2<65,A2>=7)),"Purplebox",IF((AND(B2<65,A2<=3,A2>=1)),"Orangebox",IF(AND(B2>=65,A2<7,A2>=3),"Bluebox",IF(AND(A2<7,A2>=3,B2<65),"Redbox")))))))
```

A VBA function that mimics the formula.

Comment: how can `AND(B2>10,A2=0,B2= "")` ever be TRUE.  B2 can not be greater than 10 AND "" at the same time.

Comment: Hi Rob and welcome to StackOverflow. One trick is to activate the Developer option in the menu, record a new macro, do the action you want and stop recording the macro. Then, the system has created the VBA code for you and you can start from something that works. Be careful because it works asuming you are in the same Tab, position...

Comment: My guess is that a UDF can hardly be more efficient than a core formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a go.  Total is the value returned in the cell with the function called.
It would be cell a2 and B would be cell b2 in the example
=caseTest(A2,B2)

Per Scott's note, <10 is used rather than null.  Feel free to edit.

There is also a default value if none of the conditions are met. Happy coding.

```
Function caseTest(A, B)

Dim scoreA As Integer, scoreB As Integer, result As String
    scoreA = A.Value
scoreB = B.Value

If ((scoreA >= 7) And (scoreB >= 65)) Then
    Total = "Greenbox"
ElseIf ((scoreA = 0) And (scoreB <10)) Then
    Total = "Balance"
ElseIf ((scoreA < 3) And (scoreB >= 65)) Then
    Total = "Yellowbox"
ElseIf ((scoreA >= 7) And (scoreB < 65)) Then
    Total = "Purplebox"
ElseIf ((scoreA <= 3) And (scoreA >= 1) And (scoreB < 65)) Then
    Total = "Orangebox"
ElseIf ((scoreA >= 3) And (scoreA < 7) And (scoreB >= 65))) Then
    Total = "Bluebox"
ElseIf ((scoreA >= 3) And (scoreA < 7) And (scoreB < 65))) Then
    Total = "Redbox"
Else
    Total = "default"
End If
    caseTest = Total
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to supply an input to the UDF, you can grab the row number and worksheet using `Application.Caller`. Otherwise, you can add two arguments for the `A2` & `B2` range and compare the value there.

I have made no performance tests regarding the two methods, but I would imagine the one that does **not** use `Application.Caller` would be the one that has greater performance - but I figured another example wouldn't hurt.

## Application.Caller Method

```
Function myFunc() As String

    Dim r As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Application.Caller.Worksheet
    r = Application.Caller.Row

    If ws.Cells(r, "B").Value >= 65 And ws.Cells(r, "A").Value >= 7 Then
        myFunc = "Greenbox"
    ElseIf ws.Cells(r, "B").Value > 10 And ws.Cells(r, "A").Value = 0 Then
        myFunc = "Balance"
    '.... Continue
    End If

End Function
```

Which the worksheet formula would look like: `=myFunc()`. *(no arguments needed)*

---

## Function with Arguments Method

```
Function myFunc(rngA As Range, rngB As Range) As String

    If rngB.Value >= 65 And rngA.Value >= 7 Then
        myFunc = "Greenbox"
    ElseIf rngB.Value > 10 And rngA.Value = 0 Then
        myFunc = "Balance"
    '.... Continue
    End If

End Function
```

Which the worksheet formula would look like: `=myFunc($A2, $B2)`.

As already mentioned in the comments by Scott Craner, `AND(B2>10,A2=0,B2= "")` isn't logically correct. `B2>10` and `B2=""` will never be **True** when used together with `AND`, so you may need to figure your intentions out with that one.

Answer (score 0):

if you need help on creating custom functions below link is an useful guide
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f.

To answer your question, I have created a custom function based on what I deciphered from your formula.

```
Function Cust_SetBox(A as Range, B as Range) As String
'function will receive two parameters A and B as ranges and return back a string
   Application.Volatile 'this ensures that formula will update when cell values are modified

   'Original formula
   '=IF((AND(B2>=65,A2>=7)),"Greenbox",IF((AND(B2>10,A2=0,B2= "")),"Balance",IF((AND(B2>=65,A2<3)),"Yellowbox",IF((AND(B2<65,A2>=7)),"Purplebox",IF((AND(B2<65,A2<=3,A2>=1)),"Orangebox",
   'IF(AND(B2>=65,A2<7,A2>=3),"Bluebox",IF(AND(A2<7,A2>=3,B2<65),"Redbox")))))))

   'adding .value="" condition as emtpy cells will show up as true while checking for X.Value<n
   If B.Value = "" And A.Value = "" Then
       Cust_SetBox = "Unknown"
   ElseIf (B.Value = "" Or B.Value > 10) And A.Value = 0 Then 'you might want to check this condition as it is not clear from your formula
       Cust_SetBox = "Balance"
   ElseIf B.Value >= 65 And B.Value <> "" Then
       If A.Value >= 7 Then
           Cust_SetBox = "Greenbox"
       ElseIf A.Value < 3 Then
           Cust_SetBox = "Yellowbox"
       ElseIf A.Value < 7 And A.Value >= 3 Then
           Cust_SetBox = "Bluebox"
       End If
   ElseIf B.Value < 65 And B.Value <> "" Then
       If A.Value >= 7 Then
           Cust_SetBox = "Purplebox"
       ElseIf A.Value <= 3 And A.Value >= 1 Then
           Cust_SetBox = "Orangebox"
       ElseIf A.Value < 7 And A.Value >= 3 Then
           Cust_SetBox = "Redbox"
       End If
   Else
       Cust_SetBox = "Unknown"
   End If



End Function
```

To quickly add this function to your workbook. 
use Alt+F11, insert a new module and add above code to the module. You should be able to use this new function as a formula.
Go to any cell and type the below
=Cust_SetBox(A1,B1)
The cell will show the value based on the logic above. Detailed explanation in the link above.

**Note**

Make sure Calculation is set to automatically calculate (in Formulas menu -> Calculation options) else press F9 to calculate

The workbook has to be saved as a macro enabled file else the function will not be available later.

Comment: Thank you - this is perfect